# Shortcodes - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have created shortcode for posts, now point is i need to shortcode post in post/page which works. Example i embed post2 in post1 and when i visit post1 i see that post2, but when i embed post1 in page1 i dont see post2

This is code i have written so far.

```
<?php 
function getPostShortcode( $atts, $content = '' ) {
        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'id'    => '',
            'title' => ''
        ), $atts, 'post_shortcode' ) );

        if ( empty( $atts['id'] ) )
            return;

        $loop = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'p'         => $atts['id']
        ) );
        ob_start();
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                            $desc  = ! empty( $atts['desc'] ) ? $atts['desc'] : get_the_content();
            ?>
                <div class="post-single-shortcode-aka">
                    <h2><a href="#"><?php echo $title; ?></a></h2>
                    <p><?php echo $desc; ?></p>
                </div>
           <?php 
           endwhile;
           wp_reset_postdata(); 
       } 
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'post_shortcode', 'getPostShortcode' );
?>
```

Comment: Difficult to follow, have you tested adding  `global $post;` before your WP Query. Please then add `wp_reset_query` at the end.

Comment: I have tried, it doesn't help, ty

Comment: Are you saying embedding 'post 1' in 'page 1' not showing 'post 1' (because in your question you are saying as 'post 2' not displaying)?

Comment: You have two posts and one page, when i put shortcode of post2 in post1 and then when i put shortcode of post1 in page1 i dont see post2, what im saying is that shortcodes are not working in more then 2 layers...

Comment: does it show the shortcode clearly ( [post_shortcode id=post2] ) or nothing ?

Comment: It showes [post_shortcode id=post2], i've just found solution that works for excpert and that is i can add double brackets, but that would be very confusing for editors

Comment: @Armin. I see nothing wrong with your code. The shortcode should work on post/page wherever you put it. I just noticed, why are you using the shortcode's attribute `title` as the post's title? you can you use `get_the_title()` instead. Maybe you just got confused because you are not seeing the post title whenever you use the shortcode without the title attribute ex: [post_shortcode id="2"]. Just try replacing the `echo $title` to `get_the_title()` and you'll see. And remember `id` attribute must be a post ID.

Answer (score 2):

Normal practice would be to "apply" shortcodes or filters recursively. i.e. ***each*** time you get post content then you "do_shortcode".

Within your function you can use"*get_post_field*" to get the content, or title, or excerpt etc etc for the post ID. Depending on how you want your output rendered you can use either *apply_filters* or *do_shortcode*;  and there is probably no need for ob buffering.

```
function getPostShortcode( $atts, $content = '' ) {
  extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '', 'title' => ''
  ), $atts, 'post_shortcode' ) );
  if ( empty( $atts['id'] ) ) return;

 // get_post_field can be used to get content, excerpt, title etc etc
  $desc = get_post_field('post_content',  $atts['id']);

  $myEmbed = '<div class="post-single-shortcode-aka"><h2><a href="#">' . $title .'</a></h2><p>';
  $myEmbed .= apply_filters('the_content',$desc) . '</p></div>';
  // *** OR *** do_shortcode($desc) . '</p></div>';
  return $myEmbed;
}
add_shortcode( 'post_shortcode', 'getPostShortcode' );
```

**Edit:**  added missing `</div>` to above code.

I have tested code and: If Post A contains `[post_shortcode id=1234 title="Embed 1"]` then "Post B" (id 1234") is embedded in Post A. If Post B contains `[post_shortcode id=3456 title="Embed 2"]` then "Post C" (id 3456) is also embedded in BOTH Post B AND Post A.